# encrypting data signals using the time variations between two independent coupling functions

Tags: encryption

There was a recent article about a [new encryption technique](http://gizmodo.com/new-unbreakable-encryption-is-inspired-by-your-inside-1558124990) that encrypts "using the time variations between two independent coupling functions".

What is this technique they are referring to?

Comment: Did you read the article? That technique you're asking about is described in the paper [“Coupling Functions Enable Secure Communications”, Phys. Rev. X 4, 011026, Published 26 February 2014 by Tomislav Stankovski, Peter V. E. McClintock, and Aneta Stefanovska](http://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.4.011026). **This paper is linked to from the first sentence of the Gizmodo article.** I would say this is a perfect example of lack of research, making this a low-quality question. The result is, that – to me – ***it's unclear what you are actually asking…*** Did you read that paper?

Answer (score 2):

I found [the paper](http://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/68367/1/PhysRevX.4.011026.pdf).

At a glance, this seems to be a solution in search of a problem. Unless I've missed something, there is essentially no attempt in their paper to cryptanalyze such a construct. Nor do they appear to build upon, relate to, or even reference any preexisting concepts in modern cryptography or information theory such as [computational indistinguishability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_indistinguishability) or [semantic security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security).

They also highlight some "advantages" of their system that, to someone with moderate familiarity of cryptography, seem pointless. For instance, statements like

> It results in an unbounded number of encryption key possibilities...

are indicators that the authors aren't familiar with the *actual* threats facing current cryptosystems. The entire space of 256-bit keys will never be enumerated in the lifespan of the universe, assuming our current understanding of information theory and physics are even remotely accurate. Nobody is clamoring for new cryptosystems with arbitrarily-large keys.

In my (admittedly non-expert) opinion, I find it highly implausible that any widely-used cryptosystem will ever be built upon the ideas in this paper.

Comment: *“Found” the paper*? That paper is linked to in 3 of the 4 links of that Gizmodo article OP mentioned and linked. Please don't tell me you really did a *search* to find [the publication page](http://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.4.011026) and according [PDF](http://journals.aps.org/prx/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevX.4.011026)… ;)

Comment: I followed the links from Gizmodo and thought it was just the abstract. I didn't notice there was a link to actually download it from there!